# Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type when requesting Token from Spotify API

Tags: angular, token, spotify, http-status-code-415

I am trying to request a token from spotify api to use in my app.
But I am getting a "415 unsupported media type" error.

How can I get past this error?

1. I've tried this in POSTMAN and it seems to work fine.
2. I've tried to change Content Type from x-www-form-urlencoded to JSON and vice versa that didn't help.

```
getToken() {
  let clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  let clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  let apiURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret));

  let params = new HttpParams();
  params.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

  this.http.post(apiURL+ params, { headers })
    .subscribe((res: IToken) => {
      console.log('token: ', res.access_token);
      console.log('expires in (s):', res.expires_in);
      console.log('Object: ', res);
      this.token = res.access_token;
      this.expiration = new Date().getTime() / 1000 + res.expires_in;
      console.log('now: ', new Date().getTime() / 1000);
      console.log('expiration: ', this.expiration);
    });
}
```

Please see images for error in chrome console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vLnm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlSte.png

Comment: Can you change to  

this.http.post(apiURL+ params,  headers )
And check the content type of spotify want to received is it a application/x-www-form-urlencoded or application/json

Comment: Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json.     Still giving 415

Comment: then yoh should change to application/json not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: i did but it still give 415 error

Comment: Mine you upload your source code somewhere so I can take a look ?

Comment: @IbraheemGhaffar can you create stackblitz?

Comment: how do create stackblitz with my app?

Comment: go there [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) and click angular then paste your code in there

Comment: https://github.com/s00179906/SpotfyAPIAngular  ive put it up on github

Comment: It seems that your parameters won't be added. When you look at your screenshots, there is no grant_type in the url. Can this cause the issue?

Comment: i changed the url to put in the grant_type and still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, have you tried passing the headers into the `HttpHeaders()` constructor directly? I've seen weird things happen sometimes when trying to `.append()` or `.set()` headers after instantiating them.

Try changing your headers/params code from:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret));
```

To:

```
...

const encodedClient = btoa(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`);

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedClient}`
});

const params = new HttpParams({
   'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
});

...
```

I have no guarentee that this will fix your issue, but from your pictures I can see that the headers/params aren't displaying and it might be a good thing to try.

I hope you get it working!

I've used the Spotify API in the past for a side project written in Angular if you're interested in references to things: [SpotifyTelevision](https://github.com/immannino/SpotifyTelevision)